# Merge 3 images in a single convert command mantaining size ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

With these 3 separates codes I create the following 3 images with desired size for each one. I'm failing in merging in a single command.

**This code produces P1.png**

```
convert \( \( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 1" \) \
           \( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 2" \) \
 +smush +2 -write P1.png \) null:
```

**P1.png (854x37)**

[image: enter link description]

**This code produces P2.png**

```
convert \( \( -size 881x488 xc:"#FFE97F"  \) \
           \( -size 881x488 xc:"#00FF90" \) \
            +smush +6 -resize 1180x441! -write P2.png \) null:
```

**P2.png (1180x441)**

[image: enter link description]

**This code produces P3.png**

```
convert \( \( -size 1104x89! xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 48 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Different boxes" \) \
-write P3.png  \) null:
```

**P3.png (1104x89)**

[image: enter link description]

If I join the 3 images in an image editor visually (like Paint.net) the resulting image is of 1180x606 and the resolution is 96 pixels per inch.

How can I join these 3 commands in a single "convert" command in order the final image be of 1180x606 in size?

I've tried with this code, but I don't know how to construct the command correctly

```
convert \ 
\( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 1" \) \
\( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 2" \) \
+smush +2 \ 
-write mpr:numbers \ 
\
\( 
\( -size 881x488 xc:"#FFE97F" \) \
\( -size 881x488 xc:"#00FF90" \) \ 
-resize 1180x441! +smush +6 mpr:numbers +swap -gravity center -smush +15 +gravity \ 
-write mpr:boxes \ 
-delete 0 \ 
\ 
\( -size 1104x89! xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 48 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Different boxes" \) \ 
mpr:boxes +swap -gravity center -smush +24 +gravity +write POut.png \) null:
```

**The desired output is like this:**

[image: enter link description]

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

When I see it in an image editor (Paint.net in my case) I can see and change resolution withot change pixel dimentions. Only dimentions of inches change.

**Result.png original with Resolution=120 pixel/inch and size 1180x606**

[image: enter link description]

**Result.png changed to Resolution=96 pixel/inch and size still is 1180x606 but inches dimentions changed**

[image: enter link description]

**UPDATE 2**

fmw42's code works fine creating from scratch 3 images and then merging them. My problem is if I use the same fmw42's script but instead to create
the yellow and green boxes I crop them from another image (source.png) the result.png is not the same. What is the issue when I add the cropped images?

I'm using this code:

```
convert \
source.png +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 \
\( \
\( -size 1104x89! xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 48 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Different boxes" \) \
\) \
\
\( \
\( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 1" \) \
\( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 2" \) \
+smush +2 \
\) \
-smush +24 \
\
\( \
\( mpr:img -crop 881x488+71+376   \) \
\( mpr:img -crop 881x488+992+376  \) \
+smush +6 -resize 1180x441! \
\) \
-smush +15  \
resultX.png
```

**This is source.png**

[image: enter link description]

**And this is the output that is not correct**

[image: enter link description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want? ImageMagick 6 command could be like the following as one way to do it:

```
convert \( \( -size 1104x89! xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 48 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Different boxes" \) \
-write P3.png  \) \
\
\( \( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 1" \) \
\( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 2" \) \
+smush +2 -write P1.png \) \
-smush +24 \
\
\( \( -size 881x488 xc:"#FFE97F"  \) \
\( -size 881x488 xc:"#00FF90" \) \
+smush +6 -resize 1180x441! -write P2.png \) \
-smush +15 \
result.png
```

[image]

Note that I may not have used the same font as you.

Please review:

https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#smush
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#write

**To answer your Update2 question:** You need to resent the gravity with +gravity after you have used it with -gravity center. Also you need to add +repage after your crops.

```
convert \
source.png +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 \
\( \
\( -size 1104x89! xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 48 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Different boxes" \) \
\) \
\
\( \
\( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 1" \) \
\( -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Number 2" \) \
+smush +2 \
\) \
-smush +24 +gravity \
\
\( \
\( mpr:img -crop 881x488+71+376 +repage \) \
\( mpr:img -crop 881x488+992+376 +repage \) \
+smush +6 -resize 1180x441! \
\) \
-gravity center -smush +15  \
resultX.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hi fmw42, thanks for your answer. That seems to work, but sorry, I wasn't precise in my original post since I would like to create the final image without the need to create temporal files (P1, P2,P3), because of that I've been trying without success with mpr. Is possible to do it saving on memory p1, p2 and p3 with mpr?

Comment: Those were there because you created them in your command. Just remove the -write P1.jpg etc. and it should work without them.

Comment: You're right. Removing -write px it works. The size is correct, the only thing is how to add the resulting image have a resolution of 96 pixels/inch?

Comment: Hi fmw42, I added "-density 96" at the end bu doesn't change the resolution to final image, `-density 96 result.png` Maybe you could know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: density does not change the pixel dimensions. It only change the print size in inches. If you want to change the pixel dimensions use -resize. If you want to change the pixels and density use -resample. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have last question I hope. I'm using exactly your code except that I try to crop the yellow and green boxes instead of create them from scratch but the output is incorrect. Maybe you can help me seeing why I mean in my UPDATE 2. Thanks

Comment: See my added information at the end of my post about resetting +gravity and +repage with regard to your question about cropping. Crop depends upon the gravity setting. Your measurement were made top-left relative, but you cropped center relative.

Comment: Thanks for the fix for cropped images. Is closed to my desired output. But adding the +gravity before cropping the images makes that the both previous images be not in the center. I've tried adding -gravity center in different places and I couldn't put in the center both images. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand your last comment? Did my last post not do what you want? If that is the case, please clarify why it did not work and what you are trying to do, now.

Comment: If you look your own first answer, you'll see that the box dark blue that contains "Different boxes" and the 2 blue boxes that have the text "Number 1 and Number 2" are located horizontally in the center. Well, in your second output the cropped images are located correctly, but the top dark blue box and the other 2 blue boxes are not in the center. Both are located a kind to the left.

Comment: I have edited my last answer to correct for the centering by adding -gravity center near the end before the last -smush 15 so that the bottom image is center aligned with the previous top two images.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42.  Now it works great! I was trying to add -gravity center to the top images because of that nothing happenned. The correct as you did was to center aligned the bottom image. New lesson for me. Thanks again so much.

Answer (score 1):

With well considered use of ImageMagick's memory registers, like "mpr:something", you can simplify the construction of your entire image to something like this...

```
convert -gravity center -background white -font helvetica \
   -size 1104x89 xc:"#00137F" -fill white -pointsize 48 \
   -annotate +0+0 "Different boxes" -write mpr:diffbox +delete \
   -size 426x37 xc:"#4FA7FF" xc:"#4FA7FF" -fill black -pointsize 32 \
   -annotate +0+0 "Number %[fx:t+1]" +smush 2 -write mpr:numbox +delete \
   -size 588x441 xc:"#FFE97F" xc:"#00FF90" +smush 4 \
   mpr:numbox +insert -smush 15 mpr:diffbox +insert -smush 24 result.png
```

That works for me on Windows Ubuntu bash shell running ImageMagick 6.8.9-9. You'll have to specify your own font, and if you're using the same font for everything you only have to specify it once.

Comment: Hi GeeMack. Thanks for your solution either. It works pretty fine too in a completely different way to do it. I see I need to learn a lot about it. How to add a resolution of 96 pixel/inch without change the size?

Comment: You can add "-density 96" to the command without affecting the dimensions in pixels. But remember, if you set the density before the "-annotate" operations you may have to specify different pointsizes to get the results you want.

Comment: Hi GeeMack. I added "-density 96"  at the beginning and `-smush 24 -density 96 result.png` and in other places and doesn't seem to make any change in resolution.

Comment: Setting the resolution with "-density" won't change the appearance of the image. It's mostly only relevant when the image is printed or when reading in vector images, etc. You may be looking to do something like "-resample" which will adjust the dimensions. Find out more about using "-resample" at this link – https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resample

Comment: Hi GeeMack. I think is not resampling nor resize, but actually resolution. May you see my update in original post where I show about the resolution. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the resolution will change the reported size in inches or millimeters, but it doesn't change the dimensions in pixels. The reported size in inches only has bearing on the print size, or possibly the size on the page when the image is imported into a word processor or PDF editing program. If you use "-density 96" the image will still be 1180 pixels wide and 606 pixels high.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. I want to import the image in Power Point and looks smaller with different resolutions even it has the the size in pixels.